# Return text on JSON at controller with Resource in ASP .NET Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, controller, return

I have a controller that return a JSON text .
I write a function for it and have resource too for multi language.
but when I debug it it does not  returns text.
It returns just txt  : EmailExist

Comment: switch (newsLetter)
            {
                case NewsLetterResult.EmailExist:
                    {
                        return Json(new
                        {
                            text = _localizer["ExistsMembership"].Value
                        });  
                    }
                case NewsLetterResult.Success:
                    {
                        return Json(new
                        {
                            text = _localizer["SuccessfulMembership"].Value
                    });        
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have?

```cs
switch (newsLetter)
{
    case NewsLetterResult.EmailExist:
        return Json(new { text = _localizer["ExistsMembership"].Value });

    case NewsLetterResult.Success:
        return Json(new { text = _localizer["SuccessfulMembership"].Value });

    default:
        return Json(new { text = _localizer["UnknownMembership"].Value });
}
```

The return type of your method matters, it should normally be `IActionResult` for MVC endpoints - my test method for this question / answer looks like this (I don't have your localizer so I just returned the key):

```cs
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var newsLetter = NewsLetterResult.EmailExist;

    switch (newsLetter)
    {
        case NewsLetterResult.EmailExist:
            return Json(new { text = "ExistsMembership" });

        case NewsLetterResult.Success:
            return Json(new { text = "SuccessfulMembership" });

        default:
            return Json(new { text = "Unknown" });
    }
}
```

This works as expected / required:

```json
{
    "text": "ExistsMembership"
}
```

Note the following:

1. You should always include a default case for options that don't match the options you specify.
2. You don't need to wrap the case statements in brackets.

### Newer syntax

If you are using C# 9 you can use new switch expressions and pattern matching which I personally prefer:

```cs
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var newsLetter = NewsLetterResult.EmailExist;

    return newsLetter switch
    {
        NewsLetterResult.EmailExist =>
            Json(new { text = "ExistsMembership" }),

        NewsLetterResult.Success =>
            Json(new { text = "SuccessfulMembership" }),

        _ =>
            Json(new { text = "Unknown" })
    };
}
```

This does the same thing as switch / case, and the `_` at the end has the same purpose as the `default` case in the earlier example.

Comment: yes it is . I inject localizer too. but after debug I see just this text: SuccessfulMembership
I want to return resource of it

Comment: Two things then: a) does the code I posted work for you (as a test), and b) can you post more of your code please?

Comment: I find it I write the wrong controller name thanks so much